# How can I get another condition for a df?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using 2 for loops to go through 2 variables, in each of the
variable the main df is being filter, all works fine except if the
filter for that specific variable is None, then I got an error.

```py
test1 = df.loc[df['CAR'] > 7000 | df['CAR'].isnull().any()]
```

However there is no value at all into this specific category. How can
I enter another condition where is `None` or lower than 7000 then the
values that I normally get from that example: color,  price etc will
be equal to 0 or N/A?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like what you might want to try out is the Pandas `clip` function. [Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html) is the documentation for it.

You can clip all values lower than 7000 to be np.nan values or 0, whichever you prefer.

Comment: Thanks, so any idea how to add the clip into that line? Seems it does the same right before the exception | no?

Comment: I would have posted an example showing you what to implement into your code, but i didn't fully understand what you want done. I will assume you want to `clip` all the values under 7000 in the column `CAR` so you should do something like this `df['CAR'].clip(lower=7000, inplace=True)`. Hope that helps!